# Как проводить аутентификацию и авторизацию?

Tags: java, auth

Есть java веб-приложение и обычные формы входа и регистрации.
В системе будет 2 типа пользователей:

1. пользователь;
2. админ.

Каким способом осуществлять **аутентификацию** (напрямую в сервлете или фильтром)?

Как при каждом переходе производить **авторизацию** пользователя (по сессии я так понимаю)?

В инете нашел только [аутентификацию через xml файл](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html), но я так понимаю, что это не подходит, так как люди находятся в БД.

Comment: Взять готовый фреймворк http://shiro.apache.org/

Comment: почему не использовать spring security?

Comment: в приоритете всё же хочется в ручную описать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, уточните для себя понятия [аутентификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [авторизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). И еще для [веба](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5). В последнем обращаю внимание на дайджест-аутентификацию.

Если коротко, то клиент передает не пароль, а хеш пароля. На серверной стороне для пароля (из базы) нужно также вычислить хеш. А далее сравнить хеши.

На своем уровне этот метод обеспечивает безопасность за счет использования односторонних математических функций.